# Linear Algebra and Invertibility of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given Square Matrices A,B,C such that
$$\begin{cases}
A+B+C+\lambda AB=O \\
A+B+C+ \lambda BC=O \\
A+B+C+ \lambda CA=O
\end{cases}$$
and $\lambda$ a real nonzero number, show that  $I+\lambda A, I+\lambda B, \textrm{ and } I+\lambda C$ are invertible, that $AB=BC=CA,$ and that
$A=B=C.$

Comment: You should show us what you've been trying. This is not a solve_my_homework_for_me site. ;)

Comment: Please I am completely confused and indeed i have no more powers on these matter anymore. Anyone that can help would be welcomed and I would be grateful!

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I understand completely the comment and so I add: It is indeed a homework problem that I totally got stack on. I had other similar invertibility problems on the set which with some algebraic manipulations got to the end. This one got me fill almost five pages of algebra and I feel like I'm chasing my tail...

Comment: I am very sorry if I got some of the members irritated but I believe that the truth is always the best answer. And this is that I am almost completely done with my homework and the only problem which escapes me after almost a month is this one where I don't seem to get anywhere after endless algebraic manipulations...And it is not that I ll post the solution the motive for my question but to see some creative way of thinking which I might investigate and so would jelp me with this as with other similar problems.

Comment: We had the same question already 2 weeks ago at this site.

Comment: @Dietrich do you have a link?

Comment: @Ghianni I think at least you can formulate the question in a way not as a simple exercise given by a teacher/book or something like that (as it is now is too imperative) :)

Comment: It might be useful to note that the first equation can be rewritten as
$$
A + (I + \lambda A)B + C = 0
$$

Comment: I am very grateful to all of you for your support as I am indeed a completely fresh and ignorant member of the site. I will try to reformulate  my problem and to upload what I 've done so far after I 'll study a little more about LaTeX so it wouldn't be to annoying to read it.